# Regex on an integer not producing results

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Where the eventString = {"Timestamp":1487204364889,"UserEvent":"Fireworks"}

```
eventString = JSON.stringify(event);
Timestamp = eventString.match(/"Timestamp":^\d+$/)[1];
eventType = eventString.match(/"UserEvent":"([^"]+)"/)[1];
```

The eventType is producing a result in the form of a string. The Timestamp, which is an integer, does not.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Timestamp = eventString.match(/"Timestamp":(\d+)/)[1]`? You did not define any capturing group in the pattern, but try to access the `[1]` item in the resulting array. The anchors also seem to be misplaced.

Comment: Why are you stringifying the object to get its properties. Shouldn't you just use `event.Timestamp`?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, that worked correctly. Please create an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: @Iorek can you answer my question?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, I tried this but can't get it working in AWS lambda for some reason. I resorted to regex as a result.

Comment: @Iorek can you post more code? You probably missed something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define any capturing group in the pattern, but try to access the `[1]` item in the resulting array. The anchors also seem to be misplaced.

I recommend deleting the anchors and setting the capturng parentheses around the digit matching pattern:

```
Timestamp = eventString.match(/"Timestamp":(\d+)/)[1];
```

Note that it is a good idea to first assign the match result to a variable and check if it is not null, and only then access the captured value to avoid issues.

Comment: But **why???** He can just access them in the `event` object (`event.Timestamp`), right?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: **That** is not the question. The question is about why the regex used with `String#match` did not return any match. It is not about how to access a specific value in some object. Certainly, if there is some JSON object, it is more appropriate to use appropriate methods, etc.

Comment: Please see his last [**comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354020/regex-on-an-integer-not-producing-results?noredirect=1#comment71859097_42354020)!